# Netezza SQL show only last year's data

Tags: sql, date, netezza

it sounds simple and it should be simple but for some reason I can't seem to make it happen in Netezza... So far I tried:

```
select * 
from table 
where placed_dt >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0);
```

and it looked like `dateadd` function doesn't work on Netezza. So I tried:

```
select * 
from table 
where placed_dt between (current_date - interval 1 year) and current_date
```

but still had no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: instead of interval 1 year, try current date - 365 days?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246728/netezza-date-function-for-current-date-16-days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the last year from the current date:

```
where placed_dt >= current_date - interval '1 year'
```

Note that the single quotes are needed.

and you can include the `<= current_date` if that is also needed.

If you want the last *calendar* year, there are various methods, but one is:

```
where date_trunc('year', placed_dt) = date_trunc('year', current_date) - interval '1 year'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    placed_dt >= ADD_MONTHS(DATE_TRUNC('year', current_timestamp), -12) AND
    placed_at < DATE_TRUNC('year', current_timestamp);
```

In the above inquality in the `WHERE` clause, for a current year of 2020, the lower bound represents `2019-01-01` and the upper bound represents `2020-01-01`.